# Data not inserted but have no error PHP using bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, database, bindparam

i have a simple code to input data to my database 
using prepare and bind_param

there is no error but my data are not inputted into database

```
  $stmt1 = $mysqli -> prepare ("INSERT INTO equipment(eqp_type, eqp_name, eqp_qty, eqp_usd, $eqp_idr) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt1->bind_param('sssss',$eqp_type, $eqp_name, $eqp_qty, $eqp_usd, eqp_idr);
  $eqp_type = 'BUC';
  $eqp_name = 'BUC test';
  $eqp_qty = '1';
  $eqp_usd = '0';
  $eqp_idr = '0';
  $stmt1->execute();
```

is there any idea why there is no error but my data are not inputted into database ?

Comment: Are you actually executing the query?

Comment: Where is your execute statement?

Comment: because you did not execute the query

Comment: sorry, i did executing it, i will revice this post

Comment: check my answer @ChristianAnthony

Comment: Look at `$eqp_idr` in the statement prepare and `eqp_idr` in the bind.... you're likely to be getting an unknown column error based on that value of `$eqp_idr` if you're handling errors properly.... and make sure the variables exist before binding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might forget to execute it.

You can do it with following code:

```
$stmt1->execute();
```

So your code would look as follows:

```
$eqp_type = 'BUC';
$eqp_name = 'BUC test';
$eqp_qty = '1';
$eqp_usd = '0';
$eqp_idr = '0';
$stmt1 = $mysqli -> prepare ("INSERT INTO equipment(eqp_type, eqp_name, eqp_qty, eqp_usd, eqp_idr) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt1->bind_param('sssss',$eqp_type, $eqp_name, $eqp_qty, $eqp_usd, $eqp_idr);
$stmt1->execute();
```

**Manual**

[PHP: mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: sorry, i did executing it, i will revice this post, but its still not working

Comment: What about variables? They should be before `bind_params` like in my code above

Comment: Welcome :) I'd grateful for accepting my answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your query using

```
$stmt1->execute();
```

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: sorry, i did executing it, i will revice this post, but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `$stmt1->execute()` and you will get error as you also missed `$` in `eqp_idr`